# Convert differential equation to variational statement

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, finite-element-method, variational-analysis

I know how to convert a differential equation with constant coefficients to variational form. But the question in the picture has non-constant coefficients. How do people get around that?

Any suggestion will a be great help!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: As the differential operator is, after multiplication with $x$, of the Euler-Cauchy type, you could just take the transformation $x=e^t$ to get an equation with constant coefficients and apply the method you know. Substitute back in the integral.